# This PDO prepare statement won't work *how do i fix*?

Tags: php, pdo

```
$checkUser1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
$checkUser = $handler->prepare($checkUser1);
$checkUser->execute(array(':username' => $username));
$cU = ($checkUser->rowCount());
```

This won't work, I'm not really sure how I should fix it.
It's a PDO prepare statement.

Comment: There's no `:username` placeholder in the prepared statement. The whole point of using prepared statements is so that you DON'T do variable substitution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
$checkUser1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
```

should be

```
$checkUser1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username";
```

This way you can bind the variable to the parameter like you are trying in your execute array.